# How to extract articles python goose with New York Times

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, goose

I am trying to extract articles from The New York Times using the python goose extractor.

I have tried using the standard url retrieval way:

```
g.extract(url=url)
```

However this yields an empty string. So I have tried the following way recommended through the documentation:

```
import urllib2
import goose
url = "http://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2015/12/21/world/africa/21reuters-kenya-attacks-somalia.html?_r=0"
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
response = opener.open(url)
raw_html = response.read()
g = goose.Goose()
a = g.extract(raw_html=raw_html)
a.cleaned_text
```

Again an empty string is returned for "cleaned_text". The html is retrieved from the website. I have tried as well using requests however the same result.

I am presuming this is a python goose problem in not being able to extract the article body from the raw data that is being returned. I have searched prior but I can't find any results that solve my problem.

Comment: I have resolved it by bypassing using python goose and using BeautifulSoup instead. 

    `BeautifulSoup.opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())`
    
`response = opener.open(url)`

`raw_html = response.read().decode('utf8')`

    `soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)`

    `paragraphs = soup.findAll('p',{'class':'story-body-text story-content'})`
edit: trying to get the format working but alas, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the goose has traditionally had problems with New York Times because (1) they redirect users through another page to add/check cookies (see curl below) and because (2) they don't actually load the text of articles on page load.  They do it asynchronously after first executing ad display code.

```
~ curl -I "http://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2015/12/21/world/africa/21reuters-kenya-attacks-somalia.html"
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: Varnish
Location: http://www.nytimes.com/glogin?URI=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2Freuters%2F2015%2F12%2F21%2Fworld%2Fafrica%2F21reuters-kenya-attacks-somalia.html%3F_r%3D0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 22 Dec 2015 15:46:55 GMT
X-Varnish: 1338962331
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-API-Version: 5-0
X-PageType: article
Connection: close
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: RMID=007f01017a275679706f0004;Path=/; Domain=.nytimes.com;Expires=Wed, 21 Dec 2016 15:46:55 UTC
```